# Sort string that express a time and take the one closest

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, algorithm, sorting

I have an array like this:

```
const array = ['Monthly', 'Annually', 'Quarterly', 'Annually', 'Quarterly', 'Monthly'];
```

After removed the duplicates I should get an array like this:

```
const array = ['Monthly', 'Annually', 'Quarterly'];
```

Now I should get the shortest period. I have thought to associate every string with a number so transforming the array in this way:

```
const array = [{name:'Monthly', order:1}, {name:'Annually',order:3}, {name:'Quarterly',order:2}];
```

and then compute the min according the order.

Do you have some other proposal to improve the algorithm? could be improved?

Answer (score 1):

One small improvement:

Removing duplicates is redundant, as it will require `O(n)` space, or `O(nlogn)` time, since it is a variant of [element distinctness problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Element_distinctness_problem), while finding minimal value can be done in `O(n)` time and `O(1)` space.

Also, not sure what your "order" exactly is, if it is something that is calculated once at compile / pre-processing and is constant, that's fine, as long as you don't sort the list for each query

Comment: `order` is just a value that I put there when the function is executed to compute the min